# \renewcommand{\frac}{\mfrac} but in subscript/superscript

Tags: subscripts

Can I renewcommand conditionally if displaystyle, superscript/subscript?

I have:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

Equation:
{\renewcommand{\frac}{\mfrac}\begin{equation}
   x^{\frac{1}{2}}
 +\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}}\relax

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need something like:

```latex
\begin{equation}
   x^{\frac{1}{2}}
 +\mfrac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of `\mfrac`. If you want to use it, do, but use `\mfrac` when you really want it. Whether using `\mfrac` or `\frac` depends on several factors usually involving the formula you want to typeset. For instance, `\mfrac` in front of `\int` would possiblye appear out of place.

Here's a way to cope with the problem and also keep care of not doing wrong things with commands defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand`, for which `\let` is quite dangerous.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\newif\ifsmallfractions
\newcommand{\smallfractions}{\smallfractionstrue}
\newcommand{\normalfractions}{\smallfractionsfalse}
\NewCommandCopy{\latexfrac}{\frac}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{%
  \ifsmallfractions
    \mathchoice{\mfrac{#1}{#2}}%
      {\latexfrac{#1}{#2}}%
      {\latexfrac{#1}{#2}}%
      {\latexfrac{#1}{#2}}%
  \else
    \latexfrac{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Equation:
\begin{equation}\smallfractions
   x^{\frac{1}{2}}
 +\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Normal equation:
\begin{equation}
   x^{\frac{1}{2}}
 +\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Better typesetting:
\begin{equation}
   x^{1/2} +\tfrac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You can declare `\smallfractions` anywhere and it will obey the normal grouping rules.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! And exactly what I need!

Comment: Ops! My LaTeX release does not support `\NewCommandCopy`. Can I use `\let` instead?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Update. You can use `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package.

Comment: Ok, but in my case it works only if I put `\smallfractions` outside the displaymath ambient.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Sorry, but this is not possible. You need it outside in case you use alignment environments.

Comment: Indeed I'm using `align`. I thought it wouldn't make a difference. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This retains the original size of `\frac` in scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle, while using `\mfrac` in text and display styles.  Original frac can be recovered using `\lfrac`.

EDITED, per David's suggestion, to account for `\frac`'s new-found robustness...using `\LetLtxMacro` instead of a simple `\let`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,letltxmacro}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\LetLtxMacro\lfrac\frac
\renewcommand\frac[2]{\mathchoice
  {\mfrac{#1}{#2}}
  {\mfrac{#1}{#2}}
  {\lfrac{#1}{#2}}
  {\lfrac{#1}{#2}}
}
\begin{document}

Equation:
\begin{equation}
   x^{\frac{1}{2}}
 +\frac{1}{2} +\lfrac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Uhm, I'd avoid `\dfrac` as copy of the original `\frac`. `\dfrac` is defined by `amsmath`.

Comment: This isn't really safe as `\frac` is a robust macro in recent releases so `\lfrac` doesn't save the original definition it just saves `\protect\frac `   (try `\show\lfrac` so you could end up looping

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would a substitution of `\LetLtxMacro\lfrac\frac` resolve that issue?

Comment: yes, exactly:-)